# magento attributes from database

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have created 3 attributes for order purposes.

I can see it in the order view.

Now i am using  `fooman pdf customizer`.

I am trying to get the values on the pdf when i print orders but it wont show up.

How do i accomplish this??

```
pickupdate, comment, pickup_location1
```

For the values i am using `CMS IDEAS - ORDER ATTRIBUTES`

i have added the following to my order transaction email which works fine.

```
{{var customerObject.getpickupdate()}}
{{var customerObject.getpickup_location1()}}
{{var customerObject.getcomments()}}
```

but when i put these in the Fooman module it shows up blank
i need a variable code on achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Under Frontend Properties Set "Used in Product Listing" to YES